# Refactor if-else php code

Tags: php

Sorry, noob question. What's the best way to refactor this?

```
if (is_dir('temp'))
{
  ===== do action A =====
}
else
{
  mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755);
  ===== do action A =====
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a *need* to refactor this? I don't really see it.

Comment: Not sure you would need to...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (!is_dir('temp'))
{
   mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755);
}
===== do action A =====
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
if (!is_dir('temp'))
{
    mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755);
}
===== do action A =====
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use this 'shorthand' for `if` blocks that only contain one line of code.

```
if(!is_dir('temp'))
    mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!is_dir('temp')){ mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0755); }

===== do action A =====
```